# Comprehension of multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, for-comprehension

I know JavaScript, but have no idea what the real JavaScript is. So I have decided to learn  the inner workings of the language from scratch.

I was browsing the MSDN and reading about Arrays when I stumbled on the Comprehension info. I was wondering, is it possible to use values of more than one array and connect them in the comprehension itself?

I tried something like this:

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
var arr2 = [4, 5, 6];

var arr3 = [i*j for (i of arr1, j of arr2)];
```

It didn't work of course, as well as some other constructions I checked - and the internet didn't fill my curiosity. The only hint I got from [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2113-Using-Array-Comprehensions-in-Javascript-1-7.htm), but the code there doesn't exactly do what I want.

Is there any relation between the statements and expressions used in the comprehension and outside? In the URL above there are multiple 'for each' used, and as for now, I failed to learn how to build those constructions from standard expressions.

Comment: `var arr3 = [i * j for (i of arr1) for (j of arr2)];`

Comment: Yes, but it outputs 9 elements, each times each, I want to have simple 3 elements array on the output, with arr1[0]*arr2[0], arr1[1]*arr2[1] etc.